# I have Entity Framework 6.2 I am trying to find all columns in a table that have a type of date time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have tables where

```
    public string Field1
    public datetime? Field1Updated
    public string Field2
    public datetime? Field2Updated
    public string ImportantField3
    public datetime ImportantField3Updated
```

These table have 100s of field each with its own Updated conterpart

I want to select.where datatype is DateTime or DateTime?
with something like

```
    List<TableModel> m = db.Table.Where(x=> x.TypeOf = "DateTime").ToList()
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: That's not a job for an ORM at all. Either use reflection on the client to find all `DateTime` properties or query eg the `system.columns` table for all columns that have a date-related type

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you care which properties or columns have a date type? If you want to automatically update an auditing field, the best way to do this is with a trigger on the database table.

Comment: If you want to find changes eg for synchronization or another type of processing, you can use SQL Server's change tracking and avoid auditing fields altogether. If you want to update those auditing fields on the client, you could modify the setter of the primary fields and set the corresponding audit field to the current time

Comment: There are options to automate updates to auditing fields too. You can use [Shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) to hide auditing fields from the entities. You can overload the `SaveChanges` method of a DbContext to find changes and update the shadow properties [as shown here](https://trailheadtechnology.com/entity-framework-core-2-1-automate-all-that-boring-boiler-plate/).

Comment: Yes I am trying to do the same as trigger would do on the backend db but its a bit inaccessible so I was trying to do it purely in the front end.  I suppose the main question is can you and how would you get the type of a data field entity in software?

Comment: First, use two equal signs when testing and not one.  Second, db.Table.Where is enumerating through rows of the table and not columns so you cannot test TypeOf on a DataRow.  You would need to enumerate through the columns.  What you really need is : List<TableModel> m = db.Table.Where(x=> x.Field1Updated.Date == DateTime.Parse("4/16/2019")).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to search the fields of the entity class:

```
var m = db.Table.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0].GetFields().Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(DateTime) || f.FieldType == typeof(DateTime?)).Select(f => new { f.Name, f.FieldType }).ToList();
```